# Getting error when injecting Generic class with Assisted injection

Tags: java, guice

1. Generic class `DynamoDbUtil`.

```
public class DynamoDbUtil<T> {
    private final DynamoDbEnhancedClient ddbClient;
    private final DynamoDbTable<T> mappedTable;

    @Inject
    public DynamoDbUtil(
            @Named("someNamedthing") final DynamoDbEnhancedClient ddbClient,
            @Assisted final String tableName,
            @Assisted final Class<T> beanClass
    ) {
        this.ddbClient = ddbClient;
        this.tableName = dynamoDbConfigMap.get(tableName);
        this.mappedTable = ddbClient.table(this.tableName, TableSchema.fromBean(beanClass));
    }
}
```

2. Factory for assisted injection:

```
public interface DynamoDbUtilFactory {
    <T> DynamoDbUtil<T> create(String tableName, Class<T> beanClass);
}
```

3. In the below class I am trying to inject `DynamoDbUtil`.

```
@Singleton
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    private final DynamoDbUtil<DynamoDbStore> dynamoDbUtil;

    @Inject
    public ChildClass(final DynamoDbUtilFactory dynamoDbUtilFactory) {
        this.dynamoDbUtil =
                dynamoDbUtilFactory.create("my-table", DynamoDbStore.class);
    }
```

4. Module Code:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                .implement(new TypeLiteral<DynamoDbUtil<?>>() {}, DynamoDbUtil.class)
                .build(DynamoDbUtilFactory.class));
```

But I getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) [Guice/KeyNotFullySpecified]: com.demo.factories.DynamoDbUtilFactory cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Unknown Source)
    at com.demo.Driver.main(FashionHubService.java:48)
    ... 5 more
```